# Size of nested struct fields and efficient extraction of data

Tags: matlab

I'd like to use a structure similar to the code below to store data of several measurements (metadata and values).

1. Is there a way to get the size of the 1st column of the `Data.CHANNEL` field - or doing something like `length(STRUCTURE(1).Data.CHANNEL(:,1))` - in from all 3 measurements in vector without running a `for` loop?
2. Similarly, can those data columns (1xN) be extracted to a temporary (3xN) (cell) array?

Thanks for any help!

```
   % Example Data
    x1= (1:100);
    x2= (1:105);
    x3= (1:99);
    % Fill structure usually over results(i) in a for loop
    STRUCTURE = struct;
    STRUCTURE(1).Title = 'NAME 1';
    STRUCTURE(1).Data.CHANNEL = repmat(x1, 3, 1)';
    STRUCTURE(2).Title = 'NAME 2';
    STRUCTURE(2).Data.CHANNEL = repmat(x2, 3, 1)';
    STRUCTURE(3).Title = 'NAME 3';
    STRUCTURE(3).Data.CHANNEL = repmat(x3, 3, 1)';
    save('STRUCTUREFILE','STRUCTURE')
    S=load('STRUCTUREFILE.mat');
    % How to get e.g all lengths / sizes of the first Channel for all three STRUCTURES         (measurements)?
    S.STRUCTURE(1).Data.CHANNEL(:,1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ASantosRibeiro has it right. Here's another way to do it, also answering the second question.

```
data = struct2cell(S.STRUCTURE);

% // Extract the CHANNEL components only
dataChannel = [data(2:2:numel(data))];
dataChannelStruct = cell2mat(dataChannel);

% // Question #1
lengthOfEach = arrayfun(@(x) size(x.CHANNEL, 1), dataChannelStruct);

% // Question #2
firstColumnOfEach = arrayfun(@(x) x.CHANNEL(:,1), dataChannelStruct, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

Going with your example, the outputs of the last two lines are:

```
lengthOfEach =

   100   105    99

firstColumnOfEach = 

    [100x1 double]    [105x1 double]    [99x1 double]
```

**NOTE:** This is assuming that `Title` is first, followed by `Data.CHANNEL` in your structure.  If you reverse the order, or if you add anything else to the structure, then the code won't work.

Answer (score 0):

something along this should solve your problem.

```
data_subfield={(STRUCTURE.Data.CHANNEL)};
data_field_size=cellfun(@(x) size(x),data_subfield,'UniformOutput',0)
```

Simple example:

CODE:

```
a(1).data=[10,20,30];
a(2).data=30;
a(3).data=[1,20];

zzz=cellfun(@(x) length(x),{(a.data)},'UniformOutput',0)
```

OUTPUT:

```
zzz = 

    [3]    [1]    [2]
```

Comment: I just tried this code in MATLAB and it doesn't work.  Gives me the following error: `Dot name reference on non-scalar structure.`

Comment: the code should be right. I just edited so that an example is also provided.

Comment: If you copy and paste the code in the OP's post, with the exception of saving to file and reloading, then use what you have here, it gives me that error.  I'm not sure why to be honest!